# How to search Html table data with search parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table which i am populating with JSON data,
there is an search field i have provided which is giving the tabledata on search,
Now what i am trying to do is

- I have an `select` dropdown which is consist of Table header names
- On click of that option i want to make my search to that specific column only
- suppose here i have one column name as `User Code` ,so from dropdown when user selects user code and search any thing the table data should gets populated for user code only
- I am doing the search in tbody
- Currently my search field search for whole table

**Code Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableValue = [{
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "admin",
      "User LoginId": "admin",
      "User Password": "admin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "maiyas",
      "User LoginId": "maiyas",
      "User Password": "maiyas",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbadmin",
      "User LoginId": "cbadmin",
      "User Password": "cbadmin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbaker",
      "User LoginId": "cbaker",
      "User Password": "cbaker",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "JAYANAGAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "jayanagar",
      "User LoginId": "jayanagar",
      "User Password": "jayanagar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MALLESHWARAM MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "malleswaram",
      "User LoginId": "malleswaram",
      "User Password": "malleswaram",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "KOLAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "kolar",
      "User LoginId": "kolar",
      "User Password": "kolar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    }
  ]

  function addTable(tableValue) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) { //this one to make  thead
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) { // thid one to make tbody
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      tr.classList.add("filterData"); //hear i am adding the class in body
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var tabledata = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata);
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
        }
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
      }
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
      divContainer.innerHTML = "";
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
      table.classList.add("table");
      table.classList.add("table-striped");
      table.classList.add("table-bordered");
      table.classList.add("table-hover");
    }
  }
  addTable(tableValue)

  $("#mySelect").on("change", function(e) {
    var header = this.value;
    alert(header)
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
      var q = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      if (q === "") {
        $(".filterData").show();
        return true;
      }
      $(".filterData").hide().filter(function(i, el) {
        var d = $(el).text().trim().toLowerCase();
        console.log(q, d, d.indexOf(q));
        return (d.indexOf(q) > -1);
      }).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<select id="mySelect">
  <option disabled></option>
  <option>Distributor Name</option>
  <option>User Name</option>
  <option>User LoginId</option>
  <option>User Password</option>
  <option>User Role</option>
  <option>Active</option>
</select>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="table"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this code.

I use the selectedIndex as eq

If you enable the first option, they can search anywhere

```js
var tableValue = [{
    "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "admin",
    "User LoginId": "admin",
    "User Password": "admin",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "maiyas",
    "User LoginId": "maiyas",
    "User Password": "maiyas",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
    "User Name": "cbadmin",
    "User LoginId": "cbadmin",
    "User Password": "cbadmin",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
    "User Name": "cbaker",
    "User LoginId": "cbaker",
    "User Password": "cbaker",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "JAYANAGAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "jayanagar",
    "User LoginId": "jayanagar",
    "User Password": "jayanagar",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "MALLESHWARAM MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "malleswaram",
    "User LoginId": "malleswaram",
    "User Password": "malleswaram",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "KOLAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "kolar",
    "User LoginId": "kolar",
    "User Password": "kolar",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  }
]

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {"class": "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"}),
      $thd = $("<thead/>"),
       $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
      $trh = $("<tr/>", {"class": "text-center"});

  $.each(Object.keys(tableValue[0]), function(_,val) {
    $("<th/>").html(val).appendTo($trh);
  });
  $trh.appendTo($thd);
  $.each(tableValue, function(_, item) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {"class": "filterData"});
    $.each(item, function(key,value) {
      $("<td/>", {"class": "text-right"}).html(value).appendTo($tr);
      $tr.appendTo($tb);
    });
  });
  $tbl.append($thd).append($tb);
  $("#table").html($tbl);
}
$(function() {

  addTable(tableValue)
  $("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    var q = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (q === "") {
      $(".filterData").show();
      return true;
    }
    var fldIdx = $("#mySelect")[0].selectedIndex;
    $(".filterData").hide().filter(function(i, el) {
      var d = fldIdx === 0 ? $(el).text().trim().toLowerCase() : $("td", el).eq(fldIdx - 1).text().trim().toLowerCase()
      // console.log(q, d, d.indexOf(q));
      return (d.indexOf(q) > -1);
    }).show();
  });

  $("#mySelect").on("change", function(e) {
    $("#myInput").trigger("input");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Distributor Name</option>
  <option>User Name</option>
  <option>User LoginId</option>
  <option>User Password</option>
  <option>User Role</option>
  <option>Active</option>
</select>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: sir how can i make that addTable more good slimmer, as i am new to this i have this much of knowledge only

Comment: I changed the addTable to use jQuery too

Answer (score 1):

You should not do the searching on the actual elements (on the DOM that is), 'cause it is VERY slow. Consider searching and making changes on the initial data array instead. Let the actual `TABLE` be a mere representation visualization of the array in it's current state. Then your code and logic will become cleaner, easier to comprehend and maintain, and much MUCH faster.

Here's the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var filters = {
  header: '',
  value: ''
}; 

var tableValue = [
  {
    isVisible: true,
    data: {
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "admin",
      "User LoginId": "admin",
      "User Password": "admin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
  },
  {
    isVisible: true,
    data: {
      "Distributor Name": "KOLAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "kolar",
      "User LoginId": "kolar",
      "User Password": "kolar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    }
  }
];

function addTable(tableValue) {
  // you could also use these to construct dynamic select box
  var headers = Object.keys(tableValue[0].data); // or hardcode these somewhere

  // construct header
  var thead = '<tr><th>' + headers.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>';
  var tbody = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) { // thid one to make tbody
    if (!tableValue[i].isVisible) continue; // ignore non relevant items
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for (var header in tableValue[i].data) {
      tbody += '<td>' + tableValue[i].data[header] + '</td>';
    }
    tbody += '</tr>';
  }
  
  if (!tbody) { 
     tbody = '<tr><td colspan="'+headers.length+'">No results.</td></tr>';
  }
  
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">' + thead + tbody + '</table>';
}

function filterTable() {
  var re = new RegExp(filters.value, 'i');
  var matchContents = function(str) {
    return re.test(str);
  };

  tableValue.forEach(function(row) {
    var data = row.data;

    if (filters.header) {
      row.isVisible = matchContents(data[filters.header]);
    } else {
      for (var header in data) {
        if (matchContents(data[header])) {
          row.isVisible = true;
          return;
        }
      }
      row.isVisible = false;
    }
  });

  addTable(tableValue);
}

$("#mySelect").on("change", function(e) {
  filters.header = $(":eq("+this.selectedIndex+")", this).text();
  filterTable();
});

$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
  filters.value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  filterTable();
});

addTable(tableValue);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<select id="mySelect">
  <option></option>
  <option>Distributor Name</option>
  <option>User Name</option>
  <option>User LoginId</option>
  <option>User Password</option>
  <option>User Role</option>
  <option>Active</option>
</select>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="table"></div>
```

I also somewhat simplified `addTable()` logic, it was over complicated.

Comment: I am not sure I can agree that updating the DOM is faster than hiding and showing it

Comment: Wonna to jsPerf the case? :)

Comment: Feel free :) But on a MUCH larger table than the above. There will be next to 0 difference on such a table

Comment: Nah... I know it will be faster and then in the real world scenario I would have put it on something like ReactJS and would enable windowing on that table.

You can't deny the logic I showed here is much more straightforward and clean though, can you?

Comment: It is cleaner. My fingers were also itching to make the addTable slimmer

Comment: @jayarjo as i am new to this how can i make that even slimmer (addTable)

Answer (score 0):

You may attach user defined (your own) `columnName` property to each cell DOM object you create. Then, you can enumerate cells in search function `doFilter` and check if they `columnName` property match current filter field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableValue = [{
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "admin",
      "User LoginId": "admin",
      "User Password": "admin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "maiyas",
      "User LoginId": "maiyas",
      "User Password": "maiyas",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbadmin",
      "User LoginId": "cbadmin",
      "User Password": "cbadmin",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
      "User Name": "cbaker",
      "User LoginId": "cbaker",
      "User Password": "cbaker",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "JAYANAGAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "jayanagar",
      "User LoginId": "jayanagar",
      "User Password": "jayanagar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "MALLESHWARAM MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "malleswaram",
      "User LoginId": "malleswaram",
      "User Password": "malleswaram",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    },
    {
      "Distributor Name": "KOLAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
      "User Name": "kolar",
      "User LoginId": "kolar",
      "User Password": "kolar",
      "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
      "Active": "Y"
    }
  ]

  function addTable(tableValue) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) { //this one to make  thead
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) { // thid one to make tbody
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      tr.classList.add("filterData"); //hear i am adding the class in body
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell.columnName = col[j];
        var tabledata = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata);
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
        }
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
      }
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
      divContainer.innerHTML = "";
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
      table.classList.add("table");
      table.classList.add("table-striped");
      table.classList.add("table-bordered");
      table.classList.add("table-hover");
    }
  }
  addTable(tableValue);

  function doFilter(filterField, q)
  {
      q = q.toLowerCase();

      if ((filterField === "") || (q === "")) {
        $(".filterData").show();
        return;
      }

      // we have something to filter
      $(".filterData").hide().filter(function(i, el) {
        var rowCells = el.cells;
        //console.log('el',el.cells, filterField, q);
        for (var ci = 0; ci < el.cells.length; ci++) {
          var cell = rowCells[ci];
          if (cell.columnName == filterField) {
            var d = $(cell).text().trim().toLowerCase();
            //console.log(q, d, d.indexOf(q));
            return (d.indexOf(q) > -1);
          }
        }
        return false;
      }).show();
  }

  $("#mySelect").on("change", function(e) {
    doFilter($("#mySelect").val(), $("#myInput").val());
  });

  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    doFilter($("#mySelect").val(), $("#myInput").val());
  });
});
```

BTW ability to attach user-defined properties to any DOM object in many cases may simplify code dramatically. Just to keep things clean, you may decide to attach whole data record to the `tr` for example. Just to not interfere with standard properties, you may do it in facion of `el.appData = { field1 : value1, ... }`, and access as `el.appData.field1`. In that case you inject single `appData` property object that easy to track down in your code.