# How can I parsing JSON with Node.js in electron renderer.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron

I'd like to parse JSON formatted dataset from a web server(edit in Electron renderer.js file)

[image]

```js
refresh.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const http = require('http');
  http.get(
    'http://teamparamount.cn:8080/Paramount/filesroot?username=test', (resp) =>{
      let data = '';
      // A chunk of data has been recieved.
      resp.on('data', (chunk) =>{
        data += chunk;
      });
      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      resp.on('end', () =>{
        // console.log(JSON.parse(data).info);
        // var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
        var hhh = JSON.parse(data);
        var xxx = JSON.parse(data).info;
        // alert(typeof obj);
        // console.log(hhh.length);
        // console.log(obj);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(hhh.status);
        console.log(hhh.info);
        console.log(hhh.info[1].time);
        console.log(hhh.info.length);
        console.log(hhh.info[408]);


        // console.log(obj.info[1]);

        // console.log(obj.status);
        // console.log(obj.status.length);
        function getJsonLth(obj){
          var index = 0;
          for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            if (obj[i] == ':') {
              index++;
            }
            return index;
            // alert(json1.abc[i].name);
          }
        };
        console.log(getJsonLth(xxx));
      });
    }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
});
```

In the red circle part, the first output is JSON format dataset which server sent. The second output is the result after using ***JSON.parse(data).status***. The third output is the result after using JSON.parse(data).info. And I think ***var xxx = JSON.parse(data).info*** xxx is an array as it's showed in the third output.
However, what I wanna do is to get the size, time, type, url these value separately in each element in the array. But, as you can see, the output of ***console.log(hhh.info[1].time);*** is undefined. Also, I wanna get this array's length, and I just use ***console.log(hhh.info.length)*** and the result is 409 and I am confused about it. This result clarify it is a string not an array. And I'd like to get these value and the length of the array at the same time. What should I do? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://teamparamount.cn:8080/Paramount/filesroot?username=test returns this:

```
{"status":"success","info":"[{\"size\":\"10105\"...
```

where `info` property is a string, which has to be parsed separately. That's what you apparently trying to do in:

```
var xxx = JSON.parse(data).info;
```

But instead of `JSON.parse(data).info` you should do: `JSON.parse(data.info)`. Then you will receive your `info` array into the `xxx` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I firstly `var hhh = JSON.parse(data);` and secondly `var heh = JSON.parse(hhh.info);` and finally it works. And I have another question that bother me for a quite long time. I have a .html file and there's a table, I wanna transfer and traverse these data into that table. I have no idea about that. I would appreciate if you would give me some useful suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you should open separate question for that, 'cause I don't think I will be able to fit the response in the comment. Check my my answer to another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54569276/189673 `addTable()` is function that you need. You will have to somewhat adapt it to your case though. Do not shy away from upvoting each and every answer that helped you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the info object is a stringify object, so you need to parse it and override it, and after you will be able to read the entire data object.

```
var info = JSON.parse(data.info);
data.info = info;
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I firstly `var hhh = JSON.parse(data);` and secondly `var heh = JSON.parse(hhh.info);` and finally it works. And I have another question that bother me for a quite long time. I have a .html file and there's a table, I wanna transfer and traverse these data into that table. I have no idea about that. I would appreciate if you would give me some useful suggestions.